# Encode Multiple ints into a double

Tags: c++, encoding

I would like to encode a pair of ints in a double. For example say i wanted to pass a function:

```
foo(int a, int b)
```

but instead I want just one double to represent the two ints (ie) :

```
foo(double aAndB)
```

Currently I am doing it by having one int on either side of the decimal place (ie 10 and 15 would become 10.15) and then converting it to a stringstream tokenising and extracting the two numbers.

However, this has an obvious flaw when it comes to numbers like 10 and 10 ie it becomes 10.1.

Is there a way to do this through some tricky mathematical method so that I can pass a function a double that represents 2 ints?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this. Since you have the question tagged with `encoding`, i am assuming at some point you want to decode the double to get the two ints back. In this case do you want the encoding to be loseless?

Comment: @Paolo
1. its an interesting question.
2. because i have an abstracted type with a factory method that takes only doubles and i need to pass 2 ints

Comment: What's wrong with `10.1`? I mean if you were to write it, you also wouldn't write 10.10 if someone told you to write 10 and a hundredth...

Comment: I was thinking of trying to do it by encoding the ints into the binary of the double

Comment: @RedX But what I want ids for my function to be able to take a double and split it back to its original 2 ints. If i get 1 instead of 10 then the program wont work.

Comment: Then the question is how do you differentiate between `int(10).int(1)` and `int(10).int(10)` and `int(10).int(100)` and `int(10).int(001)`? Another way to ask is: What is the minimum number the decimal place might have?

Comment: @Ben: it's not interesting. It's just a question of the number of bits and some pointer manipulation. Or you use a union. It's simply bad design if you need to do this.

Comment: You can't even pass 0 and 1 here because 0.1 is not exactly representable.

Comment: @TobiasLangner That is your opinion, I am simply trying something out of interest to see if it can be done. Why so much negativity?

Comment: For all those that tried to dominate this method, I was already implementing this another way, I only wanted to see if this kind of ting was actually possible. Try not to poo-poo everything so fast. As a further note, thank you everyone who answered well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since (usually) a double has 64 bits in it and each int has 32 bits, you'd think that you could just store the bits into the double directly, e.g.:

```
int32_t i1 = rand();
int32_t i2 = rand();
int64_t x = (((int64_t)i1)<<32) | ((int64_t)i2);
double theDouble;
memcpy(&theDouble, &x, sizeof(theDouble));
```

... and doing that "almost works".  That is, it works okay for many possible values of i1 and i2 -- but not for all of them.  In particular, for IEEE754 floating point format, any values where the exponent bits are set to 0x7ff will be treated as indicating "NaN", and the floating point hardware can (and does) convert different NaN-equivalent bit-patterns back to its preferred NaN bit-pattern when passing a double as an argument, etc.

Because of this, stuffing two 32-bit integers into a double will appear to work in most cases, but if you test it with all possible input values you'll find some cases where the values unexpectedly mutated during their stay inside the double, and came out as different values when you decoded them again.

Of course, you could get around this by being careful only to set the mantissa bits of the double, but that will only give you 26 bits per integer, so you would only be able to store integer values of +/- 33,554,432 or so.  Maybe that's okay, depending on your use case.

My advice is, find a different way to do whatever you're trying to do.  Storing non-floating-point data in a floating point variable is asking for trouble, especially if you want your code to be at all portable.

Answer (score 4):

If you're lucky and an int is half a double you can store the ints like this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
double d;

*(int *)&d = a;
*((int *)&d + 1) = b;

int outa = *((int *)&d);
int outb = *(((int *)&d) + 1);
printf("%d %d\n", outa, outb);
```

This doesn't work generally/portability. If a double and int have the same number of bits what you want is impossible.

Comment: this will work on 32bit - most probably. But as user85509 it is not portable. But even if you restrict yourself to 32 bit integer types (there are some headers that have them) - it's a sign for bad design if you need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

A double can exactly represent an integer up to 53 bits. If you want to hold a 26-bit and a 27-bit integer, it's very easy: `double combined = bits27*67108864.0 + bits26;`

Note that 67108864 is 2^26.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define a union like this:

```
struct two_int {
    int a;
    int b;
};

union encoding {
    struct two_int a;
    double c;
};
```

But doing like this may introduce problem with portability. Double check please wether this approach appropriate to your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using binary mask and extract information from the "double".

For example:

```
double encode(int a, int b)
{
    double d = 0;
    d = d | a; 
    d = d | (b << 8);
    return d;
}

double decode(double d)
{
    a = d & 0xFF;
    b = (d >> 8) & 0xFF;
}
```

In encode part, a will be in the lower 8 bits of the double variable d, b will be in the higher 8 bits of d.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always passing two ints to this one parameter then it makes no sense to pass a double. Instead pass either the two ints as separate ints, or wrap them up in a struct.

The way you are doing it leaves you no opportunity to detect the difference between a true double and two ints. And so I conclude that you will lose no functionality by doing what I describe above.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Thanks for the advice but I am just trying something this way for now.

Comment: If he has control over the factory interface he should do this.

Comment: @Ben It might not be the answer you want to hear but it's probably the solution to your problem

Comment: Actually its neither, if you read the comment under the question, I have implemented this another way and i always had the option. All i wanted to know was if it was possible. My apologies but your answer is not an answer to the question its simply a comment.